# Python printing from functions

Tags: python, function, class, printing

For a bigger project for my school work after the holidays I need to know how I can print from different functions in a menu, as seen down below, however I cannot get it to work, using the class function is way beyond my level.

```
class C:


    def set_gen(self):
        self.birth_rate = input("whats your name")
        menu()

    def display_gen(self):
        print (self.birth_rate)
        menu()


def menu():
        q=input("press a to ask or b to print")
        if q==("a"):
            RUN = C()
            RUN.set_gen()
        elif q==("b"):
            RUN = C()
            RUN.display_gen()
        else:
            menu()
RUN = C()
menu()
```

Comment: "I cannot get it to work" - what exactly can you not get to work?????

Comment: inside class you run `menu()` which run class again, which run `menu()` again - etc. It is recursion. Do it without recursion.

Comment: Readers are generally not keen on seeing requests for "ASAP" or, for that matter, "urgent". [Read this discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) to understand why - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
class C:

    def set_gen(self):
        self.birth_rate = raw_input("whats your name: ")

    def display_gen(self):
        print (self.birth_rate)



def menu():
      RUN = C() #create a C object
      while True:
            q=raw_input("press a to ask or b to print: ")

            if q==("a"):
               RUN.set_gen()
            elif q==("b"):
               RUN.display_gen()





menu() #Call the main function
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you try to do but you create `RUN` many times so you clear `self.birth_rate` in this object - you have to create it only once. Besides you should set default value  for `self.birth_rate` because you may use `display_gen` before `set_gen` and get error because `self.birth_rate` doesn't exist yet.

Besides in class you run `menu()` which run class again and it run `menu()`. It is recursion. Better use `while True` loop.

```
class C:

    def __init__(self):
        # default value at start
        self.birth_rate = None

    def set_gen(self):
        self.birth_rate = input("whats your name: ")

    def display_gen(self):
        print(self.birth_rate)

# ---------------------------------------------------- 

def menu():

    # create object only once
    run = C()

    # endless loop till you press `q`
    while True:

        q = input("a = ask, p = print, q = quit: ")

        if q == "q":
            break # exit `while` loop
        elif q == "a":
            run.set_gen() # set value in object
        elif q == "p":
            run.display_gen() # print value in object

# ---------------------------------------------------- 

menu()
```